# Configuring Java GAE Appstats for cron job

Tags: java, google-app-engine, appstats

I configured my `web.xml` to enable appstats for my cron job. My cron job is handled by a servlet at the URL `http://myapp.appspot.com/cron/myjob` and executed once an hour.

When I access the appstats admin interface at the URL `http://myapp.appspot.com/appstats/stats`. 
I can see stats about `/appstats` URLs but not about `/cron` URLs. I was expecting appstats to record events everytime the cron job has been executed. Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <!-- Servlets -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- AppStats -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logMessage</param-name>
            <param-value>Appstats available: /appstats/details?time={ID}</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/cron/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- AppStats Servlet -->    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<!--     <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>  -->
    <!-- Default page to serve -->
</web-app>
```

**Solution**: I fixed it by putting the AppStats filter before the Guice filter

Comment: Nice work. Could you please close this question as answered? Thanks

Comment: @Sydney please close this question as anwered. :)

Comment: If you found a solution, @Sydney, you should post a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by putting the AppStats filter before the Guice filter